# Add a new Node - OpenLdap N-way

Tags: openldap

I have been running a **OpenLdap N-Way** Structure with **two Master Nodes**. This configuration have been running for some months whitout any problem. https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html

Now, I need to add a third node. The strange behavior is that, when I add this third node (clean Database), It starts to delete the entries of the others two nodes.

Seems that the "clean database" is getting replicated to the other servers, deleting several entries. It is creating a lot of problems even, to restore the backups.

I am looking for the best practice/way to add a completely new node in this environment that already is running, without losing data.

Also, is there some official documentation about the best way to Backup this environment?

Any information is welcome.

Thank you,

Comment: You need to bring it up initially as a slave node until it has populated its own database.

Comment: Well, I did not think this way. It can work well. The documentation could be more specific at this point. I've broken my production environment twice. I will test, and let you know if it works.